# Maven eclipse problems eclipse

Tags: maven, maven-2

i have a little side project with eclipse.

Whenever i try to build maven projects, the jar's won't open for me what could be the problem?
Using this open-sourced project.
https://github.com/07kit/07kit

Comment: Download this code and call "mvn clean package install" command inside of extracted folder.

Comment: I still can not open, it does create .jar(s) within the target folder but thats about it.